# Is there a way to select text through multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var range = document.createRange();
var root_node = document.getElementById("test");

// Start at the `hello` element.
range.setStart(root_node.childNodes[0], 2);

// End in the `world` node
range.setEnd(root_node.childNodes[1], 2);

range.selectNodeContents(root_node);
let sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <a href="#">hello</a>
  <span>world</span>
</div>
```

I'd like to select text but because it's in different elements it hasn't been working. Is there a way to do this?

I don't mean to highlight both words in their entirety but portions of each word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Matt answer is in the right direction, but doesn't achieve what the OP wants, which is to "span" the range across multiple elements (nodes), while using offsets within those elements.

The following achieve it:

```js
var range = document.createRange();
var root_node = document.getElementById("test");
range.setStart(root_node.querySelector('a').firstChild, 2);
range.setEnd(root_node.querySelector('span').firstChild, 3);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <a href="#">hello</a>
  <span>world</span>
</div>
```

Note how on both `setStart` and `setEnd` we pass a `text` node - this is the `firstChild` of the anchor and span elements.

For further reading on this subject, please refer to this [excellent explanation](https://javascript.info/selection-range#selecting-parts-of-text-nodes).

Answer (score 0):

You called `setStart` twice, instead of `setStart` followed by `setEnd`, and you are specifying an offset of 2 in each case, but I don't think you want an offset because that puts your node index out of range (and throws an error).

```js
var range = document.createRange();
var root_node = document.getElementById("test");

// Start at the `hello` element.
range.setStart(root_node.childNodes[0], 0);

// End in the `world` node
range.setEnd(root_node.childNodes[1], 0);

range.selectNodeContents(root_node);
let sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <a href="#">hello</a>
  <span>world</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The 2's are there purposefully. I'm meaning to start the select from the second letter of the first element and end the select at the 2nd letter of the next element.

Comment: I see, that only works if the node is a TextNode, otherwise the offset is a node offset (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart)).

Comment: Ah. I see... looks like I'll be adding an overlay so I can put text in there then select the text in that rather than the div containing all the span/a elements. Thanks for the help. I didn't know you couldn't use the text node inside the actual elements...